# NativeScript recognize if page is fully rendered

Tags: javascript, nativescript, angular2-nativescript, nativescript-telerik-ui, nativescript-angular

How is it possible to recognize, if a NativeScript Page is fully rendered and visible for the user? Best would be a method, where i can call a timestamp/console.log in it. NativeScript comes in two flavours, NS Core and NS Angular. I'm not quite sure if this fulfils this?

For NS/Cores: Event handler for Page loaded event.

```
    function pageLoaded(){
      console.log()
    }           
   <Page loaded="pageLoaded">
```

https://docs.nativescript.org/cookbook/ui/page

For NS/Angular: ngOnInit

```
    ngOnInit(){
      console.log()
    }
```

https://docs.nativescript.org/tutorial/ng-chapter-4

Answer (score 4):

For Angular I would rather use `ngAfterViewInit` rather than `ngOnInit`. The ngOnInit is way to early for anything related to NativeScript to have been finalized, more on the Angular lifecycle hooks [here](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks). Actually even in the `ngAfterViewInit` some things like the Angular bindings may still not fully resolved, so event that hook is not 100% safe that 100% of the Page and its contents have been initialized.

To my knowledge there is no single callback that you can use that will tell you when the entire Page + its content are loaded since they are separate elements. You should probably have to use each elements in that Page that you want to know has been loaded and attach it its `loaded` callback separately.